# Самый простой способ  добавить элемент в начало и удалить в конце в Java

Tags: java

Привет!

Подскажите, как Java создать динамический массив (карту) и обработать его, такого вида:
Создаем:

[20,30,40,50,60]

Добавляем  элемент в начало и убираем в конце:

[10,20,30,40,50]

Т.е. мне необходимо оставить *тело*  20,30,40,50, не трогать, а  к нему добавить *голову* 10, и убрать *хвост* 60.

Как реализовать это самым быстрым и дешевым методом это в Java?

Comment: предположу, что linked list

Comment: Здравствуйте, насколько дорого использовать это?

Comment: >что значит дорого ? производительность ? пиши нормальные, конкретные вопросы.

ну что вы придираетесь-то? Разве тут могут быть какие-то другие подходящие значения для слова "дорого"?

Comment: Дорого для Java, это значит  память, и процессорный ресурс менее всего. С помощью чего, Java не будет двигать весь массив, а просто добавит элемент в начало (насколько я понимаю, первый элемент станет ссылаться на новый, а последнему присвоим значение null, "классический" список в Си)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrew F

> создать динамический массив (карту)

для начала определись чего ты хочешь. карту или динамический массив.
Я вижу что ты используешь список, так что твой выход - интерфейс [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) и его встроенная  реализация [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

насколько дорого? что значит дорого ?  В хвосты/голову вствляет быстро. [тут подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

Answer (score 2):

> Подскажите, как Java создать динамический массив (карту)

Вы, наверное, имеете в виду map (обычно ее начинающие ошибочно называют картой)? Слово "map" имеет несколько переводов, в зависимости от контекста употребления, и здесь верный перевод - это "отображение" (этот термин пришел из дискретной математики).
Отображение в Java можно создать на базе дерева или hash таблицы, не думаю, что что-то из этого вам подойдет.

> Как реализовать это самым быстрым и дешевым методом это в Java?

Вам нужен двусвязный список:

```
 Deque<Integer> deque = new LinkedList<Integer>();
 deque.addAll(Arrays.asList(20, 30, 40, 50, 60));
 deque.addFirst(10);        // O(1)
 deque.removeLast();        // O(1)
```

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, в данном
> случае на организацию списка, вставку
> и удаление  будет затрачено меньше
> памяти и процессорного времени чем для
> "сдвига" всего массива

Есть эмпирическое правило выбора структуры данных в вашем случае:

1. Массив хорош для быстрого доступа на чтение к любому его элементу, вставки элементов в конец, удаления элементов с конца. Все эти действия выполняются очень быстро. Вставка (либо удаление) в начало или вставка (либо удаление) в середину приводят наихудшему времени (т.к. приходится выделять новый кусок памяти и копировать туда измененный массив).
2. Двусвязный список хорош для быстрой вставки (либо удаления) элементов в конце и в начале. Вставка (либо удаление) элементов в середину требует больше времени, но выполняется все-равно быстрее, чем в массиве (т.к. не требует копирования абсолютно всей структуру данных, как это необходимо для массива). Произвольный доступ к элементам (кроме, первого и последнего) в списке требует больше затрат времени, чем в массиве.

Comment: Да, спасибо. LinkedList в моем случае будет лучшим вариантом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в данном случае на организацию списка, вставку и удаление будет затрачено меньше памяти и процессорного времени, чем для "сдвига" всего массива:

    int[] array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 1000, 5000, 0, 5000];
    int[] temp = array;

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = array[i - 1];
    }

    array = temp;
    array[0] = -100; // the new input

Comment: @Andrew F массив в Яве не сдвигается. Массивы в Яве неизменяемые объекты. ArrayList основан на массиве,да. Но когда происходит вставка в середину или начало ArrayList'a, происходит копирование исходного массива. полное. Так что вот именно из-за этого ArrayList тут проигрывает.

Comment: Или первому элемент начинает ссылаться на  новый, а хвосту присваивается null? Т.е. если у меня есть ~10 000 000 элементов, и мне надо поменять только два - добавить "голову" и убрать "хвост", мне не нужно двигать "тело".

Comment: Удаление элемента в начале массива в Java приводит к тому, что мы выделяем память под новый массив где-то в другом месте, и копируем ваш массив, начиная со второго и до последнего элемента в новое место. Происходит это "глубоко" под капотом, поэтому со стороны все выглядит как обычный сдвиг массива на один элемент вниз.

Comment: При удалении хвоста ничего никуда не копируется - это быстрая операция.

Answer (score 1):

Если максимальное количество элементов известно, а добавляются и удаляются они только с головы и хвоста, то самой эффективной структурой (независимо от Java или Си или ...) будет использование массива фиксированного размера.

Только у него должна быть "плавающая" точка отсчета (так сказать, виртуальный нулевой индекс). Т.е. храните индекс "нуля" (ihead) и текущий размер (length). Индекс последнего (точнее первого свободного в хвосте = (ihead + lenght) % size).

Т.е. вставка новой головы это в ihead - 1 и length++, а удаление хвоста -- тривиально length--

Ну, думаю, далее сами разберетесь.

--

Кстати ([[@Xmaster](/users/22795/xmaster)](/users/22795/xmaster), спасибо за подсказку), подобная структура данных называется кольцевой (или циклический) буфер (cyclic buffer или ring buffer).

Comment: 
 Спасибо за совет! В моем случае, к сожалению, размер массива не определен - меняется он динамически.

>массива фиксированного размера
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в данном случае аллокатор JVM зарезервирует под него память или будет выделять динамически по мере надобности?

Comment: думаю, нужно добавить название этой структуры данных, чтоб ТС смог быстро найти примеры имплементации: кольцевой буфер.

Comment: @Andrew F, если в Java нужен массив, который растет по мере надобности, то нужно использовать [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

А для обычных массивов память выдеяется однократно и далее ее размер не меняется.

Comment: Да, понял, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю свои пять копеек:

Если размер массива фиксированный, то наилучшим образом конструкция описывается лимитированным стеком (LimitedStack). Вставка в дно стека приводит к выталкиванию с вершины стека элемента (аналогия с вертикальной трубой где, элементы добавляются/берутся только снизу).

В Guava есть такая коллекция [EvictingQueue](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html)